# swiftui view is not updated until I minimize the app and open it again even though I inject the model

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here's a very simple view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    @ObservedObject var doctestModel : DoctestModel
    
    var body: some View
    {
        ScrollView
        {
            Text(doctestModel.output)
        }
    }
}
```

I inject the model into the view in the SceneDelegate like this:

```
let contentView = ContentView(doctestModel: self.doctestModel)
```

And here is my doctestModel:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class DoctestModel : ObservableObject
{
    @Published var output : String
    var queue : DispatchQueue
    

    init()
    {
        output = ""
        let fd = rdi_hos_init()
        queue = DispatchQueue(label: "doctest_thread", qos: .utility)
        
        queue.async
        {
            // Some c code that will write to fd
            rdi_hos_run_tests()
        }
        
        queue.async
        {
            let buf_len = 4096
            let buf = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: buf_len, alignment: 1)
            var bytes_read = 0
            
            while true
            {
                bytes_read = Darwin.read(fd, buf, buf_len)
                
                assert(bytes_read != -1)
                
                if bytes_read == 0
                {
                    break
                }
                                
                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    self.output += String(bytesNoCopy: buf, length: bytes_read,
                    encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: false)!
                }
            }
            
            buf.deallocate()
            rdi_hos_run_close()
        }
    }
}
```

The code reads from a pipe that is being written to by some C code. I'm doing the reading asynchronously but then I update the @Published variable in the main thread.

Issue is the screen is going to be blank until I minimize the app, then when I open it again the view will start updating.

Debugging I found that I'm receiving the data correctly and the output variable is being updated perfectly, but for some reason the View will not update until I minimize and open again.

I saw people suggesting StateObject but I'd like to target slightly older versions of iOS.

Halp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it is because initially there is not data and scroll view got collapsed to state from which it cannot grow. Try the following

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    @ObservedObject var doctestModel : DoctestModel
    
    var body: some View
    {
        ScrollView
        {
            Text(doctestModel.output).frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```